# Rabbitmq message is not appearing in the queue from c#

Tags: c#, .net, queue, rabbitmq

I am executing below code successfully without any errors but when I am executing list_queue command it gives me no queue. Dont know where the problem is.

The below code is not giving error at all. My machine is windows 7 64x, installed AMPQ runtime 64bit and using 32x RabbitMq server v.2.8.1 .

```
private void createExchange(string message)
        {
            var queName = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientQueue"]);
            var exchangeName = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientExchange"]);
            var hostName = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"]);

            _logger.Info("entered in create exchange");
            _logger.Info("queName: " + queName);
            _logger.Info("exchangeName: " + exchangeName);
            _logger.Info("hostName: " + hostName);
            try
            {
                var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
                connectionFactory.HostName = "localhost";
                connectionFactory.UserName = "user1";
                connectionFactory.Password = "userpassword";

                using (IConnection connection =
                    connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
                {
                    _logger.Info("Conncection created");
                    using (IModel model = connection.CreateModel())
                    {
                        _logger.Info("Model is created");
                        model.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, ExchangeType.Fanout, true);
                        model.QueueDeclare(queName, true, true, false, null);
                        model.QueueBind(queName, exchangeName, "", new Dictionary<string, object>());

                        IBasicProperties basicProperties = model.CreateBasicProperties();
                        model.BasicPublish(exchangeName, "", false, false,
                                           basicProperties, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
                        _logger.Info("message: " + message);
                        _logger.Info("message published");

                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Info("Error in create exchange");
                _logger.Info("InnerException:" + ex.InnerException);
                _logger.Info("Message:" + ex.Message);
                _logger.Info("StackTrace:" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though you are declaring an 'exclusive' queue. Exclusive queues are exclusive to the connection and as such cannot be operated upon (including being listed) from another connection.

Try

```
Model.QueueDeclare(queName, true, **false**, false, null)
```

If you want to be able to list it or do anything else with if from another connection.